Profile Screen does not update ui when text field left null
FIX EDIT: Ok found the fix;
On my user model phoneNumber parameter was like this;
phoneNumber: phoneNumber ?? this.phoneNumber,
But this field was not required so i changed it to phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
And now it works.
I am using go router for navigation and provider for state management.
When i edit phone field, it succesfully updates and shows the correct phone number on the screen.
But if i leave the phone field null, it does not show the empty phone field. Instead old phone number persists on the screen. What am i missing?
Text(
                      user.phoneNumber != null
                          ? 'Telefon: ${user.phoneNumber}'
                          : 'You can add your phone number here',
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                    ),

And to update the phone number i use something like this;
{
          // Update Firebase doc
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
              .update({
            'username': _nameController.text,
            'useremail': _emailController.text,
            'bio': _bioController.text.isEmpty ? null : _bioController.text,
            'phoneNumber': _phoneController.text.isEmpty
                ? null
                : int.tryParse(_phoneController.text),
          });

Edit Profile Screen;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class EditProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProfileScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<EditProfileScreen> createState() => _EditProfileScreenState();
}

class _EditProfileScreenState extends State<EditProfileScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bioController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _phoneController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final user = userProvider.user;

    if (user != null) {
      _nameController.text = user.username;
      _emailController.text = user.useremail;
      _bioController.text = user.bio ?? '';
      _phoneController.text = user.phoneNumber?.toString() ?? '';
    }
  }

  Future<void> _saveProfile() async {
    // Asenkron işlem başlamadan önce gerekli bilgileri alıyoruz
    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final user = userProvider.user;
    final firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      try {
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
          // Firestore'daki kullanıcı dökümanını güncelle
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
              .update({
            'username': _nameController.text,
            'useremail': _emailController.text,
            'bio': _bioController.text.isEmpty ? null : _bioController.text,
            'phoneNumber': _phoneController.text.isEmpty
                ? null
                : int.tryParse(_phoneController.text),
          });

          // mounted kontrolü
          if (!mounted) return;

          if (user != null) {
            // UserProvider'daki kullanıcıyı güncelle
            userProvider.setUser(user.copyWith(
              username: _nameController.text,
              useremail: _emailController.text,
              bio: _bioController.text.isEmpty ? null : _bioController.text,
              phoneNumber: _phoneController.text.isEmpty
                  ? null
                  : int.tryParse(_phoneController.text),
            ));
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('Error updating profile: $e');
        if (mounted) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('Güncelleme hatası: $e')),
          );
        }
      }
    }

    // Profil sayfasına yönlendirme sadece mounted durumunda yapılmalı
    if (mounted) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Profil Güncellendi!')),
      );
      GoRouter.of(context).go('/profile');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Profili Düzenle'),
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            GoRouter.of(context).go('/profile');
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              // Name Field
              TextFormField(
                controller: _nameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Adınız'),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Adınızı düzenleyin';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16.0),

              // Email Field
              TextFormField(
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-posta'),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'E-postanızı düzenleyin';
                  }
                  // Simple email validation
                  if (!RegExp(r'^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+').hasMatch(value)) {
                    return 'Lütfen geçerli bir e-posta adresi girin';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16.0),

              // Bio Field (zorunlu değil)
              TextFormField(
                controller: _bioController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Hakkımda'),
                maxLines: 3,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16.0),

              // Phone Number Field (zorunlu değil)
              TextFormField(
                controller: _phoneController,
                decoration:
                    const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Telefon Numarası'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16.0),

              // Submit Button
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _saveProfile,
                  child: const Text('Kaydet'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Profile Screen;
import 'dart:io'; // Dosya işlemleri için
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import '../providers/user_provider.dart';
import '../services/image_upload_service.dart';
import '../widgets/navbar.dart'; // Servis dosyasını ekledik

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  File? _imageFile; // Seçilen fotoğrafı tutacak değişken
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    // Asenkron işlem başlamadan önce UserProvider'ı alıyoruz
    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final user = userProvider.user;

    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      });

      try {
        if (user != null) {
          debugPrint('Uploading image to Firebase Storage...');
          String imageUrl = await ImageUploadService()
              .uploadImageToFirebase(_imageFile, user.username);
          debugPrint('Image uploaded. URL: $imageUrl');

          // mounted kontrolü
          if (mounted) {
            userProvider.setUser(user.copyWith(profileImageUrl: imageUrl));
            setState(() {}); // UI'ı güncelle
            debugPrint('User model updated and UI refreshed.');
          }
        } else {
          debugPrint('User is null.');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('Error uploading image: $e');
      }
    } else {
      debugPrint('No image selected.');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Burada userProvider ve user'ı context geçerli iken alıyoruz
    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    final user = userProvider.user;

    if (user == null) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Profil'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                GoRouter.of(context).go('/settings');
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text(
            'Kullanıcı bilgisi bulunamadı.',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Profil'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                GoRouter.of(context).go('/settings');
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                            user.profileImageUrl ??
                                'https://placehold.jp/150x150.png',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: -5,
                          right: -5,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            onPressed: _pickImage, // Fotoğrafı seçme işlemi
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text(
                      user.username,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text(
                      user.useremail,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    // Telefon numarası ve bio alanlarını ekleyelim, fallback ile
                    Text(
                      user.phoneNumber != null
                          ? 'Telefon: ${user.phoneNumber}'
                          : 'Telefon numaranızı ekleyebilirsiniz.',
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text(
                      user.bio != null
                          ? 'Bio: ${user.bio!}'
                          : 'Bionuzu ekleyebilirsiniz.',
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text('Takipçi: ${user.followersCount}',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                        const SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Text('Takip Edilen: ${user.groupsJoined?.length ?? 0}',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () {
                        GoRouter.of(context).go('/editprofile');
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                      label: const Text('Profili Düzenle'),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Divider(),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('Son Yüklemeler',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.video_library),
                      title: Text('Video 1'),
                      subtitle: Text('2 gün önce yüklendi'),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.video_library),
                      title: Text('Video 2'),
                      subtitle: Text('3 gün önce yüklendi'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Divider(),
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                child: const TabBar(
                  indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.video_library), text: 'Teklifler'),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.group), text: 'Gruplar'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 400,
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        itemCount: user.uploadedVideos?.length ?? 0,
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                        ),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                user.uploadedVideos?[index].issue ??
                                    'Video $index',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: user.groupsJoined?.length ?? 0,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.group),
                          title: Text(
                              user.groupsJoined?[index].title ?? 'Grup $index'),
                          onTap: () {
                            // Grup detaylarına gitme işlemi
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const NavBar(
          initialIndex: 4,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Add the provider and textfield code

@HesamRasoulian okay, i added the full code to the post. Please take a look.

Make sure that your state management solution (Provider) is correctly notifying listeners of changes. You should use notifyListeners() or similar methods to update your UI when the state changes
  Consumer<UserProvider>(
 builder: (context, userProvider, child) {
        final user = userProvider.user;
        return Text(
          user.phoneNumber != null
              ? 'Telefon: ${user.phoneNumber}'
              : 'You can add your phone number here',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
        );
      },
    ),

also update
// Update Firebase doc
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
    .update({
  'username': _nameController.text,
  'useremail': _emailController.text,
  'bio': _bioController.text.isEmpty ? null : _bioController.text,
  'phoneNumber': _phoneController.text.isEmpty
      ? null
      : _phoneController.text, // Store as string if necessary
});


Thanks a lot for the reply. However i could not figure it out. I added the full code to the post. Please take a look if you can.

Use Consumer in your root widgets.Your code seems all good ,there was a simple statement issue.
